# Extremely long loading time for complex autolayout view

Tags: ios, autolayout, loading

In my app I have a very complex view with over a hundred subviews that all tie to each other or the superview and it takes ages to load on screen. The loading time tends to be around 6-7 seconds which is ridiculous and can't be left that way. I therefore have 2 questions.

1. Is there any reasonable way to improve performance for autolayout? I have no idea what could do the trick here but I'm really hoping I'm missing something.
2. Is there perhaps at least a way how to load it in the background? I know that changing the UI on background threads is not a good idea, but does loading the autolayout fall in this category? I really's dont feel comfortable with freezing the app for 7 seconds just to load a view and at least making it responsive meanwhile would be an improvement.

Thanks

Comment: Autolayout _does_ fall in this category. — Let's start with the obvious: are you 100% certain that it's auto layout that is causing the delay? Easy to find out using Instruments, so that should be your first step. It seems more likely, indeed, that you are doing something else time-consuming or else talking to the interface on a background thread.

Comment: I guess you need to simplify your layout, or maybe load some tihngs after you already shown the "main"-view

Comment: Matt, yes I am 100%, I have two alternative set ups with the same code just different amount of subviews and one takes 0.5 seconds and the other over 7 seconds. I also checked instruments and it definitely is the autolayout.

Johnny, the problem is that even once the main view is shown, when loading this autolayout, the app still freezes. True, the user can see the main view, but if its frozen for 7 seconds it won't be much use.

Comment: Could you post this on github as an example project? If this is really an auto layout issue, you should be able to delete most of your code so you won't be giving away any secrets. If I could play with it a little, maybe I could make a positive suggestion...

Comment: Thanks matt, I talked to the guy whom im doing this for and they dont want me to post anything, so cant do that unfortunately. I have, however, found this website: http://pilky.me/36/ which talked about optimising autolayout and shows that if i use more local constraints it can dramatically improve performance so I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved this by simply turning the whole view into a UITableView which decreased the amount of autolayout used, plus the amount of constrainst which had to be calculated at a time (off-screen cells are ignored).